# Android Studio Volley StringRequest response is Null

Tags: android, android-volley

So, I have been using Android Volley to get JSON Strings out of URLs for a project.
When I used the code for this in my MainActivity, it worked flawlessly in an onClick of a button, and I got a correct response. Here's that code:

```
public void aanmeldButtonClick(View view) {
        UserName = findViewById(R.id.Username);
        Logon = findViewById(R.id.Logon);

        Password = findViewById(R.id.Password);


        String naam = UserName.getText().toString();
        String wachtwoord = Password.getText().toString();
        String url = "http://ineke.broeders.be/2021Android/webservice.aspx?do=aanmelden&Naam=" + naam + "&Email=ll-83004@broeders.be&Wachtwoord=" + wachtwoord;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if (response.equals("true")) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.aangemeld);
                    welkomTerug = findViewById(R.id.welkomTextView);
                    welkomTerug.setText("Welkom terug, " + naam);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Naam/Wachtwoord is fout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

I  wanted to clean up my MainActivity, so I put that volley StringRequest code in a seperate method in a class. Here's that class:

```
public class DomainController {

    private static Context ctx;
    String finalResponse;

    public String JSONFromURL(String url) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                finalResponse = response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return finalResponse;
    }

    public DomainController(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }
}
```

And here's the onClick event where I call this method:

```
public void aanmeldButtonClick(View view) {
        DomainController domainController = new DomainController(this);
        UserName = findViewById(R.id.Username);
        Logon = findViewById(R.id.Logon);

        Password = findViewById(R.id.Password);


        String naam = UserName.getText().toString();
        String wachtwoord = Password.getText().toString();
        String url = "http://ineke.broeders.be/2021Android/webservice.aspx?do=aanmelden&Naam=" + naam + "&Email=ll-83004@broeders.be&Wachtwoord=" + wachtwoord;
        

        if (domainController.JSONFromURL(url).equals("true")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.aangemeld);
            welkomTerug = findViewById(R.id.welkomTextView);
            welkomTerug.setText("Welkom terug, " + naam);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Naam/Wachtwoord is fout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }


    }
```

When I press the button however, the app crashes. I used the debugger and realised that the JSONFromURL method returns null. Anyone know why this happens and how to possibly fix it?

These are the logs when it crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.CityHunt, PID: 16506
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.CityHunt.MainActivity.aanmeldButtonClick(MainActivity.java:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Can you post crash logs ?

Comment: Just added them in, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The response from

```
domainController.JSONFromURL(url).equals("true")
```

is going to be null when comparing it with "true" as Volley is async and will run on the background. Therefore before even completing the volley request your if condition will run causing null pointer exception.

Create a callback function such that when the Volley request is completed it then checks for the if condition.

Comment: I tried a callback, but I'm pretty new with android and java. I'm still getting the some error now. I am pretty sure i used the callback incorrectly though.